# How to view the full screen mode in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, fullscreen

Hai i want create  a full screen mode ,so i used this link http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/07/creating-full-screen-flex-applications/.But i cannot create a full screen mode.anybody kindly help me.

```
    <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.effects.easing.*;
        import mx.effects.Fade;
        import mx.effects.Rotate;
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        private var fade:Fade;
        private var rotate:Rotate;

        private function init():void {

            // Fade effect
            fade = new Fade();
            fade.duration=9500;
            // Rotate effect
            Alert.show("Text Copied!", "Alert Box", Alert.OK);
            stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
            img.setStyle("showEffect", fade);

        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
```

error 
[image]

Comment: What's in line 25 of your mxml? Also, can't you debug and execute init() step by step to see which line causes the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `stage` property is still `null` when the object is initialized. So you can't call

```
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
```

at the `init()` method.

You should call that when the object is added to the stage.

```
private function init():void {
    // ...
    this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStage);
}

function addedToStage(e:Event) {
    stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
}
```

Or you can do as in the link you posted:

```
private function init():void {
    // ...
    Application.application.stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
}
```

---

Another possibility for the error is that `img` is `null` too. So check that it is already created before using it:

```
private function init():void {
    // ...
    if (img) {
        img.setStyle("showEffect", fade);
    } else {
        trace("img is null.");
    }
}
```